# Intellij IDEA event log file location

Tags: intellij-idea

I have got information in `Event log` that `08:54:02 Unable to import maven project: See logs for details`

Where I can find this logs file in Intellij IDEA 15CE ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reach the event logs directory from `Help` - `Show Log in Explorer/Finder`

Comment: Yes that's it! Thanks :)